# gcc/xCode -- #include that does not trigger an error (or warning) if the file does not exist?

Tags: iphone, xcode, gcc, include, include-guards

Is this possible?

Basically, what I want to do is something like this:

```
#includeIfItExists "header.h"
```

and if header.h does not exist, the compiler simply continues on its merry way.

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: I could setup such a file and put debugging macro definitions (or debugging code, for that matter) into it.  If I don't include it in my repository, there will be no chance that pushing it to the server, and no impact on the other people working on the project.  Furthermore, it feels like by far the cleanest way to do this type of thing.

Comment: By far the easiest way is to add a "Run Script" build step at the beginning that touches the file. You'll also want to list it in the build step outputs, so XCode's dependency-tracking algorithm knows about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm by no means an expert C guy but I don't believe that this is possible natively. I think the recommend route would be to pass in a named macro at the compiler level using `-D` and if it is (or possibly is not) defined perform your include. This way the person compiling the program has to make a conscious decision to skip the include (or include it).